# Summer Shandy, anyone ever made it?

Tags: beer, clone-recipe

Anyone ever tried to make a beer like Linenkugels Summer Shandy? Its a beer brewed with lemonade... and very tasty on a hot day!! Any suggestions on how it might be made?

Comment: I doubt they actually brew it with lemonade.  I bet they blend post fermentation and pasteurize or filter out the yeast to keep it from refermenting.  I have had it many times and it is good.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried that one, but traditionally I believe shandy is a mix of beer and lemon lime soda.  i don't believe the lemon is usually fermented at all, although that may be how they do it with the beer you mentioned.

Comment: Its worth trying... a good summer beer. And avail in cans, which is nice on the golf course or at the swimming pool!

Comment: Denny is correct here.  You are better off mixing it in the glass.  The brewers of Summer Shandy make beer, filter out the yeast then add back lemonade and bottle.  You won't be able to get the high level of residual sweetness at home by just mixing it and bottling.  The yeast will consume the sugar and make bottle bombs.

Comment: I'm sure it's worth trying, but I don't think Lienie's makes it within 100 miles of here!

Answer (score 2):

Take a German beer and mix with soda or juice (Like lemonade).  You now have a radler aka shandy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandy

I enjoy mixing a Hefeweizen and lemonade.  Half and half is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, it tastes a bit like someone dumped a bunch of Countrytime Lemonade mix into a light lager or a kolsch.

You could probably do better by brewing your own lemonade with fresh lemons and adding that to the beer.   Just remember to monitor the pH; most yeast don't like the conditions below about 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Add a few ounces of Mikes Hard Lemonade to any summer (wheat) beer.  Makes a great summer drink.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to make some myself and thought I would look on line , I make wine and beer and I have made cherry beer and black berry beer successfully I do believe what ever type of lemon you use would have to be put in the primary fermentor and after two weeks you start racking to make it clearer , you will never get it completely clear ! after racking twice then you apply your priming sugar the same way you would any beer and then bottle